# What are usable characters are for package names?

Tags: deb, packaging

For example can we use `[.+_,*]` in the name? Would appreciate a link to documentation. I can't find any that specify a rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is described in the Debian Policy Manual. [Section 5.6.7](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-package) describes the `Package` field, which sets the name for binary packages.

> #### 5.6.7. `Package`
>
> The name of the binary package.
>
> Binary package names must follow the same syntax and restrictions as
> source package names. See [Source](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-source) for the details.

And:

> #### 5.6.1. `Source`
>
> This field identifies the source package name.
>
> [...]
>
> Package names (both source and binary, see [Package](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-package)) must consist
> only of lower case letters (`a-z`), digits (`0-9`), plus (`+`) and
> minus (`-`) signs, and periods (`.`). They must be at least two
> characters long and must start with an alphanumeric character.